# How to add aria-selected="false" role="gridcell" in jQuery datepicker date td?

Tags: jquery-ui-datepicker

I want to add role and aria-selected to date in TD I'm using jQuery data picker

My current code for date TD as below:

```
 <td data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="0" data-year="2014"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">2</a></td>
```

I want out-put with role and aria-selected within TD:

```
<td aria-selected="false" role="gridcell" headers="row1 Thursday">1</td>
```